# How to Preserve string with formatting in OpenXML Paragraph, Run, Text?

Tags: c#, parsing, ms-word, openxml, office-interop

I am following this structure to add text from strings into OpenXML Runs, Which are part of a Word Document.

The string has new line formatting and even paragraph indentions, but these all get stripped away when the text gets inserted into a run. How can I preserve it?

```
Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

String txt = "Some formatted string! \r\nLook there should be a new line here!\r\n\r\nAndthere should be 2 new lines here!"

// Add new text.
Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));
```

Comment: Side note: paragraph with new lines inside sounds very strange to me. Are you sure that is what you need to achieve at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [`Break`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.break(v=office.15).aspx) in order to add new lines, otherwise they will just be ignored.

I've knocked together a simple extension method that will split a string on a new line and append `Text` elements to a `Run` with `Break`s where the new lines were:

```
public static class OpenXmlExtension
{
    public static void AddFormattedText(this Run run, string textToAdd)
    {
        var texts = textToAdd.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        for (int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                run.Append(new Break());

            Text text = new Text();
            text.Text = texts[i];
            run.Append(text);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\somepath\test.docx", true))
{
    var body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    String txt = "Some formatted string! \r\nLook there should be a new line here!\r\n\r\nAndthere should be 2 new lines here!";

    // Add new text.
    Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
    Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());

    run.AddFormattedText(txt);
}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: Great! thank you so much. I just found it odd that there wasn't some kind of built in recognition for this. I'll probably build off your extension method and account for tabs too!

Comment: By any chance do you know why formatting has to be manually handled this way? I still cant understand why it (openXML) ignores the .net newline/tab characters? For example, say I copied any formatted text from a webbrowser and then pasted it into a word document. It automatically recognizes certain formatting and applies it accordingly.

Comment: I don't know to be honest @Micheal, I guess it's because it's XML and white space is handled differently to how you'd usually expect. I can't find anything definitive in any documentation that gives any reasoning though. Sorry.